# Optimal way to handle similar CRUD with Spring boot data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, crud

I'm using Spring boot data JPA.
I have 6 objects, and I want to create CRUD operator on all of them. How can I archive that without rewriting similar codes?

More detail:
Take Customer object for example.
I have to write 4-5 method for CRUD, and if I have another object I also have to write the same amount of similar method

CustomerWebAPI:

```java
package com.ecobike.core.crud.customer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerWebAPI {
    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Bean
    private void init() {
        CustomerDB.database = customerRepository;
        customerAPI = new CustomerAPI();
    }

    private CustomerAPI customerAPI;

    @GetMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> redirect() {
        return all();
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> all() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(customerAPI.getAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> getOne(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(customerAPI.get(id));
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> create(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(customerAPI.create(customer));
    }

    @PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Customer updatedCustomer) {
        Customer customer = customerAPI.get(id);
        customer.setCustomer_name("test2");
        customerAPI.update(id, customer);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(customer);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        customerAPI.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
    }
}
```

CustomerAPI

```java
package com.ecobike.core.crud.customer;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomerAPI {
    private final CustomerController controller;

    public CustomerAPI() {
        this.controller = new CustomerController();
    }

    public Customer create(Customer customer) {
        return controller.create(customer);
    }

    public Customer get(Long id) {
        return controller.get(id);
    }

    public List<Customer> getAll() {
        return controller.getAll();
    }

    public void update(Long id, Customer customer) {
        controller.update(id, customer);
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        controller.delete(id);
    }
}
```

CustomerController

```java
package com.ecobike.core.crud.customer;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomerController {
    private final CustomerRepository database = CustomerDB.database;

    public Customer create(Customer customer) {
        return database.save(customer);
    }

    public Customer get(Long id) {
        return database.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public List<Customer> getAll() {
        return database.findAll();
    }

    public void update(Long id, Customer customer) {
        database.save(customer);
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        Customer C = get(id);
        database.delete(C);
    }
}
```

CustomerDB

```java
package com.ecobike.core.crud.customer;

class CustomerDB {
    public static CustomerRepository database;
}
```

Customer

```java
package com.ecobike.core.crud.customer;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Table(name = "customer_test")
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long customer_id;
    @Column(name = "customer_name")
    private String customer_name;
}
```

CusomterRepo:

```java
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

What is the recommended way?